# How to fix "function not allowed" when using row_number() over a view?

Tags: sql, db2, rownum

```
select * from       (                                                   
select a.*,row_number() over() as rk                                    
from table1 tba  
                     ) as foo where rk between 11 and 20
```

This works for database table. I am using a  view which is a join of 2 tables. 
When i try to do rownum it is saying: "**Function not allowed**"

```
select * from       (                                                   
select a.*,row_number() over() as rk                                    
from view1 v1  
                     ) as foo where rk between 11 and 20
```

Any suggestion or alternative for rownum in DB2?

Comment: What version of DB2?  Mine runs this just fine (although it's _really slow_)...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should include the `row_number()` in your view

Answer (score 2):

The other alternative to including it in the view, as @GregM suggested, is to put it in a CTE:

```
WITH numbered as (SELECT a.*, ROW_NUMBER() OVER() as rk
                  FROM table1 as a)
SELECT *
FROM numbered
WHERE rk BETWEEN 11 AND 20
```

Please note that this is about as slow as your original code (which runs just fine on my version).